# Update query using two tables

Tags: query, ms-access

[image]

I want to update the ProductStock field in tblProduct when this query is run. The ProductStock should minus the Quantity field in tblOrderProduct. (ignore the * sign, I just wanted to see if multiplication worked). The user should be prompted to enter the OrderId beforehand

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the condition in a new column where you select the `OrderID` column.
So, in the 3rd column select Table `tblOrderProduct` and Field `OrderID` and place `[Enter Order ID]` on the Criteria line of this column.

Replace the `*` by `-`. This will subtract the `Quantity` from the `ProductStock`.

Well, and you don't need the `Quantity` column. Remove it.

In the SQL view you will see

```
UPDATE tblProduct
INNER JOIN tblOrderProduct ON tblProduct.ProductID = tblOrderProduct.ProductID
SET tblProduct.ProductStock = [ProductStock]-[Quantity]
WHERE (((tblOrderProduct.OrderID)=[Enter Order ID]));
```